# Same quantum states represented in different basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wavefunction, hilbert-space, fourier-transform

In literature on an introduction to quantum mechanics which I am working through, there is a section which explains that a *vector* has different representations based on the basis you choose and then relates this to quantum mechanics. It does this by making giving the following explanation:

> Imagine an ordinary vector $A$ in two dimensions. How would you describe this vector to someone? The most convenient way is to set up cartesian coordinates axes, $x$ and $y$, and specify the components of $A$: $A_x = \hat{i} \cdot A$,  $A_y = \hat{j}\cdot A$. Of course you could have a different set of axis $x'$ and $y'$ and the components would then be: $A_x' = \hat{i}'\cdot A$, $A_y = \hat{j}'\cdot A$. But it's the same vector.
>
> The same is true for the state of a system in quantum mechanics. It is represented by a *vector*, $\lvert\mathcal{S(t)}\rangle$, that lives "out there in Hilbert space," but we can express it with respect to any number of different bases. The wave function $\Psi(x,t)$ is actually the coefficient in the expansion of $\mathcal{S(t)}$ in the basis of position eigenfunctions: $$\Psi(x,t) = \langle x | \mathcal{S(t)} \rangle$$
> (with $|x\rangle$ standing for the eigenfunction of $\hat{x}$ with eigenvalue $x$), whereas the momentum space wavefunction $\Phi(p,t)$ is the expansion of $| \mathcal{S} \rangle$ in the basis of momentum eigenfunctions: $$\Phi(p,t) = \langle p | \mathcal{S}(t) \rangle$$
> (with $|p \rangle$ standing for the eigenfunction of $\hat{p}$ with eigenvalue $p$).

It then states that $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ contain the same information and describe the same state.

**Question:**

In the description, when it is stated that "$A$: $A_x = \hat{i} \cdot A$,  $A_y = \hat{j}\cdot A$" and "$A_x' = \hat{i}'\cdot A$, $A_y = \hat{j}'\cdot A$" for different basis. In this description $A$ is the same but it's representation is different when working out components.

Why is it then that when describing the components of a system, $| \mathcal{S} \rangle$, in quantum mechanics, $| \mathcal{S} \rangle$, that the representation of $|\mathcal{S} \rangle$ does not change when working out the components in different basis (specifically the basis consisting of position operator eigenvectors and momentum operators eigenvectors), as can be seen by the following

$$\Psi(x,t) = \langle x | \mathcal{S(t)} \rangle =   \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta(x-y)\Psi(y,t)dy$$ and

$$\Phi(p,t) = \langle p | \mathcal{S(t)} \rangle=  \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{-ipy}{\hbar}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}\Psi(y,t)dy$$

where we have basis vectors (eigenvetors) $\delta(x-y)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}e^{\frac{ipy}{\hbar}}$ respectively.

Why is the vector $|\mathcal{S} \rangle$ represented as $\Psi$ for both bases when working out the components for the quantum mechanics case above?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249400/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me rephrase those precise equations in the language of finite-dimensional linear algebra. You have a vector $A$ and two bases $\beta=\{e_i\}_i$ and  $\beta'=\{e_i'\}_i$. This means you can write the components of $A$ with respect to $\beta$ as
$$
A_i=e_i·A=\sum_j\delta_{ij}e_j·A
$$
and the components with respect to $\beta'$ as
$$
A_i'=e_i'·A=\sum_j(e_i'·e_j)e_j·A.
$$
Here the $\delta_{ij}=e_i·e_j$ is the direct equivalent of the $\delta(x-y)=⟨x|y⟩$, and the $e_i'·e_j$ is the direct equivalent of $e^{-ipx/\hbar}/\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}=⟨x|p⟩$.

Simply put, the presence of $\Psi(y,t)$ on the right-hand side of both expressions is simply because you're doing the inner products themselves in the position representation. You could equally write
$$\Psi(x,t) = \langle x | \mathcal{S(t)} \rangle =    \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{+iqx}{\hbar}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}  \Phi(q,t)dq$$ 
and 
$$\Phi(p,t) = \langle p | \mathcal{S(t)} \rangle= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta(p-q)\Phi(q,t)dq,$$ 
or any combination of the two representations for the inner products.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Does $\langle x| p \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}$ follow from $\langle x|p \rangle = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta(x-y)e^{\frac{ipy}{\hbar}}dy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}$?

Comment: @LucioD That's a circular argument. The formula for $⟨x|p⟩$ follows from a number of different things, depending on what you want to think of as fundamental. That's for a separate question, though.

Comment: Okay but is the equation $\langle x| p \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \delta(x-y)e^{\frac{ipy}{\hbar}}dy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar} }e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}$ correct? Also, I'm not following why it is a circular argument, I'm simply taking the inner product ($\langle f , g \rangle := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^* g dx$) of the eigenvector $\langle x| = \delta(x-y)$ and $| p \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar} }e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}$.

Comment: Because it assumes the position-space wavefunction of momentum states, $⟨y|p⟩=e^{ipy/\hbar}/\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}$, for the inner product. (Note also that $⟨x|=\delta(x-y)$ and $|p⟩=e^{ipx/\hbar}/\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}$ are incorrect and inconsistent.) I'm not particularly interested in explaining further - if you still have a question, you can ask it separately.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty To confirm what you stated in your answer, which references finite dimensional linear algebra. If you want to express $\Psi$ in terms of the basis of Hamiltonian eigenfunctions i.e. $|n \rangle.$ Then $\Psi(x,t) = \sum_nc_ne^{\frac{-iE_n t}{\hbar}}\psi_n(x)$, does this correspond to $\langle x | n \rangle = c_n e^{\frac{-iE_n t}{\hbar}}$ and $\psi_n(x) = e_j \cdot A$?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the vector |S⟩ represented as Ψ for both bases when working out
>   the components for the quantum mechanics case above?

The first of the final two equations is simply an expression for the sifting property of the delta 'function'.

$$f(x) = \int dx' f(x')\delta(x - x') $$

Let's back up just a bit and write the state (ket) as a weighted 'sum' of position basis kets

$$|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle = \int dx'\: |x'\rangle\langle x' | \mathcal{S}(t)\rangle  = \int dx'\: |x'\rangle \Psi(x',t)$$

Here, $\Psi(x',t) = \langle x' | \mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$ is, for a specific $x'$, a complex number, the 'amount' of $|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$ in the $|x'\rangle$ 'direction'.

Weighting the basis ket $|x'\rangle$ by this number and then 'summing' over all these components, we get back the ket $|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$ (since the position basis is complete).

Now, contract both sides with the position basis bras $\langle x |$ to find

$$\langle x|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle  = \Psi(x,t) = \int dx'\: \langle x|x'\rangle \Psi(x',t) = \int dx'\: \delta(x - x')\Psi(x',t)$$

But we could have chosen the momentum basis kets $|p\rangle$ instead and then, rerunning the above, end up with

$$\langle p|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle  = \Phi(p,t) = \int dp'\: \langle p|p'\rangle \Phi(p't) = \int dp'\: \delta(p - p')\Phi(p',t)$$

However, these formal expressions don't actually help us *find* the $\Psi(x,t)$ and $\Phi(p,t)$.  But, assuming we have solved for the components of $|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$ on one or the other basis, we can find the components on the other basis.

It follows, from the commutation relation for the position and momentum operators, that

$$\langle x | p\rangle = \frac{e^{i\frac{p}{\hbar}x}}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}$$

and

$$\langle p | x\rangle = \frac{e^{-i\frac{p}{\hbar}x}}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}$$

Then, starting with

$$|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle = \int dx'\: |x'\rangle\langle x' | \mathcal{S}(t)\rangle  = \int dx'\: |x'\rangle \Psi(x',t)$$

and then contracting with the *momentum* basis eigenbras, find

$$\langle p|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle  = \Phi(p,t) = \int dx'\: \langle p|x'\rangle \Psi(x',t) = \int dx'\: \frac{e^{-i\frac{p}{\hbar}x'}}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\Psi(x',t)$$

which is the 2nd of your final two equations expressing the relationship of between $\langle p|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$ and $\langle x|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$

Comment: This is a very good answer. One question, is the $\langle x| x' \rangle = \delta (x-x')$ defined in this way for the reasons that there exists a type of orthonormality when treating it as a scalar product (which it is not, since the position basis is not square integrable) and thus it is analogous in a way to the finite dimensional case of the Kronecker delta? Or is it derived from something else?

Answer (score 1):

Take the inverse Fourier transform of your last equation,
$\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int e^{i p x/\hbar}\phi(p,t) dp$, to see that the "coefficients" of $\psi(x,t)$ are *not* the same in the two representations: in the $x$ representation, the coefficients are $\psi$ and in the $p$ representation, the coefficients are $\phi$.