# What are origins of the definitions for the momentum and position operators in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

For that matter what is origin for the energy operator?
I now they are defined as:
$\hat{x} = x$
$\hat{p} = i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$
$\hat{E} = -i\frac{d}{dt}$

I understand they might not have strict derivations as such but I am just looking for some sort of justification for them.
Also I wanted to understand the origin of the commutation relations between them?

Thank you

Comment: Commutation relation can be traced back to classical mechanics (Hamilton mechanics) in which there is something called Poisson bracket.

Comment: I don't believe that $\hat{E}$ is defined to be $-i\frac{d}{dt}$

Comment: See, for example, [Why can't $iℏ\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$
be considered the Hamiltonian operator?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17477/9887)

Comment: Related  : [Hermiticity of Momentum Operator (matrix) Represented in Position Basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280178/hermiticity-of-momentum-operator-matrix-represented-in-position-basis/423506#423506).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three core facts:

1. For a particle with a well-defined wavelength $\lambda$, the spatial dependence goes as $\psi \sim e^{i kx}$ for $k=2\pi/\lambda$, and therefore
   $$
   -i\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \psi = k \,\psi.
   $$
2. The de Broglie relationship between momentum and wavelength reads
   $$
   p = \frac{h}{\lambda} = \frac{h}{2\pi/k} = \hbar k,
   $$
   and if you substitute that into the above, you have
   $$
   -i\hbar\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \psi = \hbar k \,\psi = p \,\psi.
   $$
3. Finally, this needs to be extended from wavefunctions that have well-defined wavelengths to wavefunctions that don't, and this is done by postulating that this extension be done in a linear way, i.e. that if $\psi = e^{ik_1x}+ e^{ik_2x}$ is a superposition of two matter waves with different momenta, then $\hat p\psi = p_1 e^{ik_1x}+ p_2e^{ik_2x}$, i.e. the momentum acts separately on the two components. Depending on how much of the theory you've already laid down, this is probably a brand-new postulate ("matter waves are linear") and it doesn't "come from" anywhere - you just postulate and see if it works to explain experiments. (Which, of course, it does.)

---

As for the energy operator, it's the same thing, but now you swap in the Planck relation $E=h\nu$ where the de Broglie relation used to sit.