# Position-space representation of momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

I have found 2 different forms of $⟨x|\hat{p}|x′⟩$ and I have no idea which one is the true form. Can anyone help please?

1. $⟨x|\hat{p}|x′⟩ = (i\hbar)\frac{d\delta(x − x′)}{dx′}$
2. $⟨x|\hat{p}|x′⟩ = -(i\hbar)\frac{d\delta(x − x′)}{dx}$

Comment: You'll get confused to no end if you do not stick to the [canonical representation picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Spinless_position%E2%80%93space_wave_function), $\hat p = \int dx |x\rangle \frac{\hbar}{i} \partial_x \langle x|$, from which you prove what you choose.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76299/2451

Comment: Related : [Hermiticity of Momentum Operator (matrix) Represented in Position Basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280178/hermiticity-of-momentum-operator-matrix-represented-in-position-basis/423506#423506).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\langle \psi | A | \varphi \rangle = \langle \varphi | A^{\dagger} | \psi \rangle^*$, you have to conjugate your first line.
You get
$$\langle x | p | x' \rangle = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-x')$$
or
$$\langle x | p | x' \rangle = \langle x' | p | x\rangle^* = [-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\delta(x-x')]^* = i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\delta(x-x') = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-x')$$
so both are the same result now.