# Can I define $\hat{x}$ as $x\delta(x'-x)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Operators can be thought of as matrices. Since matrices have two indices and involve summing:

$A^i_j \psi^j\equiv A^i_0\psi^0 + A^i_1\psi^1 + A^i_2\psi^2 \dots$

and a summation between 2 vectors turns into an integral in the continuum:

$\psi_i \psi^i \to \int dx \psi^*(x) \psi(x)$

The usual definition of the position operator:

$$\hat{x}\psi(x) = x\psi(x)$$

involves neither summing, nor has two indices.

I discovered this definition $\hat{x}\equiv \delta(x'-x)x$

such that:

$$\hat{x}\psi(x) = \int dx \delta(x'-x)x\psi(x) = x'\psi(x')$$

which involves summing and has two indices $x, x'$, and it reduces to the original definition. Does this appear anywhere? How would one define momentum operator then? I know it's needlessly complicated, but it helps me grasp some other concepts.

Comment: The integration has to be over $x'$, the result should be $x\psi(x)$, not $x'\psi(x')$ since $x'$ is auxiliary integration variable.

Comment: I.e. $[\hat{x}\psi](x) = \int dx' x'\delta(x'-x)\psi(x') = x\psi(x)$.

Comment: It doesn't matter it's a variable name, but I believe mine is accurate because similar to how vectors change indices: $\psi^i \to A^j_i \psi^i = \psi'^j$.

Comment: You should have an $x'$ rather than an $x$ on the LHS: $(\hat x \psi)(x')$.  You are integrating over $x$, so the output  of the integral  cannot depend on $x$.

Comment: @Habouz it does matter, you wrote an expression that is not true except when $x=x'$. One way to fix this error is as I have described, the other one is as mike has described.

Comment: Related : My answer here [Hermiticity of Momentum Operator (matrix) Represented in Position Basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280178/hermiticity-of-momentum-operator-matrix-represented-in-position-basis/423506#423506). See equations (12)-(15).