# How can difference of two operators produce a constant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

In the canonical commutation relations, $$[\hat{x}, \hat{p}] = \hat{x}\hat{p} - \hat{p}\hat{x} = i \hbar $$ Both $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ are operators and so are $\hat{x}\hat{p}$ and $\hat{p}\hat{x}$. How does their difference turn out to be a constant? Shouldn't it also be an operator?

Comment: The RHS is missing the identity operator $I$ - which is usually omitted for notation convenience...

Comment: $i\hbar$ has to be understood as $i\hbar I$...

Comment: The operators also must act on a wave function, which is why it is often discouraged to write the operators this way. This reads "the commutator of position and momentum acting on a wave function returns the wave function times a constant."

Comment: Related : [Hermiticity of Momentum Operator (matrix) Represented in Position Basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280178/hermiticity-of-momentum-operator-matrix-represented-in-position-basis/423506#423506).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantities that are not commuting in your example are the Hermitian operators associated with the position and momentum observables.

$$
\hat{x} = x
$$

$$
\hat{p} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$

By substituting these operators into the commutation relation, and remembering that they act on a dummy wavefunction $\psi(x)$ you get:

$$
[\hat{x},\hat{p}] \psi(x) = \hat{x}\hat{p} \psi(x) - \hat{p}\hat{x} \psi(x) = -i\hbar x \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} -  -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( x \psi(x)\right)
$$

This requires the product rule to evaluate the derivative in the 2nd term.

$$
[\hat{x},\hat{p}] \psi(x) = -i\hbar x \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + i\hbar \psi + i\hbar x \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} = i\hbar \psi(x)
$$

The resultant operator is then simply $[\hat{x},\hat{p}] = i\hbar$

Et voila.