# Momentum and position operator in momentum basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, fourier-transform

I was recently studying Quantum mechanics from R.Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics.
I recently encountered improper vectors, and function and infinte-dimensional vectors. But I got confused at a point:
The book introduced a hermitian operator that takes the derivate of a ket $|{\psi} \rangle$ from the Hermitian operator K which is defined as: $$K_{xx'}=-i\delta'(x-x')$$
Then it solved for the eigenfunction of K:$$\psi_k(x)=Ae^{ikx}$$
where k is the eigenvalue and $\psi_k$ is the corresponding eigenfunction. Then the book proved:
$$\langle k|k'\rangle=\delta(k-k')$$
here k depicts eigenfunction in vector form. The book then Introduces the X operator and does some maths(I didn't understood a thing,except that it multiplies a function by x.). Then the book says:
In the k basis, K operator just multiplies with the function with k while the X operator becomes $i\frac{d}{dx}$.
I wanted to give it a try,$$K_{kk'}=\langle k|K|k'\rangle$$ $$K_{kk'}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\langle k|x\rangle\langle x|K|x'\rangle\langle x'|k'\rangle dxdx'}}$$   $$K_{kk'}=C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\delta(x-x')e^{-ikx}e^{ik'x'}dx'dx}}$$   $$K_{kk'}=C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-ikx}e^{ik'x}dx}$$ which corresponds to:$$K_{kk'}=\langle p|p'\rangle$$ Which is not accurate(The above integral was taken from the book only).The Calculation for X in k basis was even more terrible. So here is my question:

- What is the X operator actually?
- What is wrong with my calculations above?
  I hope you guys will help me, I want to know Where I am getting it wrong, I hope you ideas will help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wrote down $K_{xx'}$ wrong. It should be $K_{xx'} = -i\delta'(x-x')$.

Comment: What is the $\hat{X}$ operator? It is the operator that acts as multiplication by $x$ on position-space wave functions, i.e.,
$$
\hat{X}: \lvert{\psi}\rangle\mapsto \hat{X}\lvert\psi\rangle
\Longleftrightarrow
\hat{X}: \psi(x) \mapsto x\psi(x)\,.
$$
In other words if $\psi(x)$ represents $\lvert \psi\rangle$ in position space, then $x\psi(x)$ represents $\hat{X}\lvert\psi\rangle$ in position space.

In QM, $\hat{X}$ is an operator that corresponds to the position of a quantum particle. All of this will be spelled out in detail (you're only on Ch 1, a mathematical introduction!).

Comment: Related : [Hermiticity of Momentum Operator (matrix) Represented in Position Basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280178/hermiticity-of-momentum-operator-matrix-represented-in-position-basis/423506#423506).

Comment: @hft go easy, I edited it, my fault can revert! I was assuming the $\langle x|K|x\rangle$ used in the derivation had the correct form

Comment: @march it was my fault for editing

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Yeah, roll back the edit. My apologies to OP for assuming it was OP's fault.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic In your defense, you did not introduce the typo in OP's sixth equation. That *does* seem to be OP's fault...

Answer (score 2):

The integral in question is exactly a definition of the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History)
$$\delta(z-z^\prime)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i q(z-z^\prime)}dq.$$ I have specifically used different variables $(z, z^\prime, q)$ than the ones in the question because this is true for any variables.

When taking integrals from the book, make sure that the variables match. On one side you have $k$ and $k^\prime$ while on the other there is $p$ and $p^\prime$ - either they are the same, or you must use the definitions for how they are related to each other (and the factor of $2\pi$ might work out nicely).

Comment: sorry I meant $\langle k|k'\rangle$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Is the $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ necessary for the integral?

Comment: @Charu_Bamble Yes the $1/2\pi$ is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The last integral is equal to a Dirac delta function of k prime minus k.
In position space the X operator is the multiply by x operator, while in k space it is the pure imaginary differentiate by k operator. Similarly, in k space the K operator is the multiply by k operator and in position space it is the purely imaginary differentiate by p operator.
As a consequence of Fourrier mathematics, the eigenfunctions of the momentum in position space have the same form as the eigenfunctions of position in momentum space.